# I have added the tables in phpmyadmin but it is not working

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, datatables

So I have a source code of this website. At first it did not work so I made a new table called users then added the username, password etc after that the error has been removed when I register but when I try to login it does not work and when I go to phpmyadmin there is no new entry please look at source code and etc

```
 namespace rbxWorkshop
{
use \EasyRequest as Client;
use \DiscordWebhooks\Embed;
use \SecurityLib as SecurityLib;
use \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use \RandomLib\Factory as RandomLib;
use \DiscordWebhooks\Client as DiscordClient;

class System
{
    private $errorReporting = false;
    private $maintenanceMode = false;
    private $allowRegistrations = true;

    // Quick Checks
    public function loggedIn()
    {
        if ($_SESSION['username'] == "") {
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->isBanned($_SESSION['username']);
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function varChecks()
    {
        if ($this->errorReporting === TRUE) {
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        } else {
            error_reporting(0);
        }

        if ($this->maintenanceMode === TRUE) {
            header("Location: /maintenance.php");
        }
    }
    public function prepare($param)
    {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->database(), $param);
    }
    public function userAgent()
    {
        return "rbxWorkshop/1.1; +https://overwardnetwork.net";
    }
    public function isBanned($username)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";
        $array = mysqli_fetch_array($this->database()->query($sql));

        if ($array['banned'] == 1) {
            unset($_COOKIE['RWS_Session_ID']);
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            session_destroy();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Database
    public function database()
    {
        define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
        define("DB_USER", "overward_root");
        define("DB_PASS", "andrieX321");
        define("DB_NAME", "overward_Cookie");

        $connection = new \mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if ($connection->connect_errno) {
            exit("Failed to connect: " . $connection->connect_error);
        }
        return $connection;
    }
    public function mailUser($username, $service)
    {
        if ($this->userExists($username)) {
            if ($service == "verify") {
                $email = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/emails/email_1.min.html");

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";
                $array = mysqli_fetch_array($this->database()->query($sql));

                $email = str_replace("%username%", $username, $email);
                $email = str_replace("%code%", $array['activation_code'], $email);

                $mail = new PHPMailer;
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->Host = 'smtp.mailgun.org';
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Username = 'postmaster@mail.rbxworkshop.net';
                $mail->Password = 'f030a7e3cd1310e5e7525c287cdac4cd';
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
                $mail->Port = 465;
                $mail->setFrom('verification@rbxworkshop.net', 'rbxWorkshop');
                $mail->addAddress("{$array['email_address']}", "{$array['username']}");
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject = 'rbxWorkshop Verification';
                $mail->Body = "{$email}";

                if (!$mail->send()) {
                    $json = array(
                        'status' => "error",
                        'reason' => "{$mail->ErrorInfo}",
                    );
                    return json_encode($json);
                } else {
                    $json = array(
                        'status' => "success",
                        'email' => "{$array['email_address']}"
                    );
                    return json_encode($json);
                }
            } elseif ($service == "recover") {
            } else {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "Service parameter is unknown"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            }
        } else {
            $json = array(
                'status' => "error",
                'reason' => "User not found"
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        }
    }
    public function loginUser($username, $password)
    {
        $Security = new Security();
        $sessionID = $Security->rwsCookie();

        if ($this->userExists($username)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";
            $array = mysqli_fetch_array($this->database()->query($sql));

            if ($array['active'] == "0") {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "Account is not activated"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            } elseif (password_verify($password, $array['password'])) {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "success",
                    'username' => "{$username}"
                );
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $expiryDate = new \DateTime("+1 week");
                setcookie("RWS_Session_ID", "{$sessionID}", "{$expiryDate->getTimestamp()}", "/", "rbxworkshop.net", true, false);
                return json_encode($json);
            } elseif (!password_verify($password, $array['password'])) {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "Password is incorrect"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            } else {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "Unknown error"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            }
        } else {
            $json = array(
                'status' => "error",
                'reason' => "User not found"
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        }
    }
    public function registerUser($username, $password, $email_address, $ip_address)
    {
        if ($this->allowRegistrations) {
            $Security = new Security();
            $discord_code = $Security->lowStr();
            $activation_code = $Security->lowStr();
            $encrypted_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => '12']);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (username, password, email_address, ip_address, activation_code, discord_code)
VALUES ('$username', '$encrypted_password', '$email_address', '$ip_address', '$activation_code', '$discord_code')";
            $sql_ip = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `ip_address`='$ip_address'";
            $sql_email = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email_address`='$email_address'";

            if ($this->userExists($username)) {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "Username is already in use"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            } elseif (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql_ip)) == 1) {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "IP address is already in use"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            } elseif (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql_email)) == 1) {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "Email address is already in use"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            } else {
                $this->database()->query($sql);
                $this->mailUser("{$username}", "verify");

                $json = array(
                    'status' => "success",
                    'username' => "{$username}"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            }
        } else {
            $json = array(
                'status' => "error",
                'reason' => "Registrations are closed"
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        }
    }
    public function userExists($username)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";

        if (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql)) == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function banUser($type, $username, $discord_id)
    {
        if ($type == "discord") {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `discord_id`='$discord_id'";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql))) {
                $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `banned`=1 WHERE `discord_id`='$discord_id'";
                $this->database()->query($sql);

                $json = array(
                    'status'        => "success",
                    'discord_id'    => "{$discord_id}"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            } else {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "User not found"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            }
        } elseif ($type == "website") {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql))) {
                $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `banned`=1 WHERE `username`='$username'";
                $this->database()->query($sql);

                $json = array(
                    'status'    => "success",
                    'username'  => "{$username}"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            } else {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "User not found"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            }
        } else {
            $json = array(
                'status' => "error",
                'reason' => "Type parameter is unknown"
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        }
    }

    // Discord
    public function discordVerified($type, $username, $discord_id)
    {
        if ($type == "discord") {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `discord_id`='$discord_id'";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql)) == 1) {
                $array = mysqli_fetch_array($this->database()->query($sql));
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "success",
                    'username' => "{$array['username']}"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            } else {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "Discord ID was not found"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            }
        } elseif ($type == "website") {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";
            $array = mysqli_fetch_array($this->database()->query($sql));

            if ($array['discord_id'] == null || "") {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $json = array(
                'status' => "error",
                'username' => "Discord ID was not found"
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        }
    }
    public function verifyDiscord($discord_id, $discord_code)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `discord_code`='$discord_code'";

        if (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql)) == 1) {
            $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `discord_id`='$discord_id' WHERE `discord_code`='$discord_code'";
            $this->database()->query($sql);

            $json = array(
                'status' => "success",
                'discord_id' => "{$discord_id}",
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        } else {
            $json = array(
                'status' => "error",
                'reason' => "Discord Code was not found",
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        }
    }
    public function userWebhook($username, $service)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `webhooks` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `service`='$service'";
        if (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql)) == 1) {
            $array = mysqli_fetch_array($this->database()->query($sql));
            $json = array(
                'status' => "success",
                'username' => "{$array['username']}",
                'webhook' => "{$array['webhook']}"
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        } else {
            $json = array(
                'status' => "error",
                'reason' => "User not found",
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        }
    }
    public function webhookAnnouncement($service, $message)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT `username`, `webhook` FROM `webhooks` WHERE `service`='$service'";
        while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->database()->query($sql))) {
            $Client = new DiscordClient("{$array['webhook']}");
            $Embed = new Embed();
            $Embed->title("rbxWorkshop Global Announcement", "https://rbxworkshop.net/");
            $Embed->description("An announcement has appeared?!");
            $Embed->field("Announcement", "Hey {$array['username']}! {$message}");
            $Embed->image("https://rbxworkshop.net/logo.png");
            $Embed->color(1738495);
            $Embed->footer("rbxWorkshop");
            $Client->username('rbxWorkshop')->embed($Embed)->send();
        }
    }

    // License & Service Key
    public function isBuyer($type, $username, $license)
    {
        if ($type == "license") {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `licenses` WHERE `license`='$license'";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql)) == 1) {
                $array = mysqli_fetch_array($this->database()->query($sql));

                $json = array(
                    'status' => "success",
                    'username' => "{$array['username']}",
                    'license' => "{$array['license']}",
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            } else {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "License key was not found.",
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            }
        } elseif ($type == "website") {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `licenses` WHERE `username`='$username'";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql)) == 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $json = array(
                'status' => "error",
                'reason' => "Type parameter is unknown",
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        }
    }
    public function licenseUser($type, $username, $discord_id)
    {
        if ($type == "discord") {
            $Security = new Security();
            $license = $Security->licenseStr();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `discord_id`='$discord_id'";

            if (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql)) == 1) {
                $array = mysqli_fetch_array($this->database()->query($sql));
                $username = $array['username'];
                if ($this->isBuyer("website", "{$username}", "")) {
                    $json = array(
                        'status' => "error",
                        'reason' => "{$username} is already licensed"
                    );
                    return json_encode($json);
                } else {
                    $extension = $Security->serviceStr();
                    $mgui = $Security->serviceStr();
                    $stub = $Security->serviceStr();

                    $sql_1 = "INSERT INTO `licenses` (username, license) VALUES ('$username', '$license')";
                    $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO `service_keys` (username, service, service_key) VALUES ('$username', 'extension', '$extension')";
                    $sql_3 = "INSERT INTO `service_keys` (username, service, service_key) VALUES ('$username', 'mgui', '$mgui')";
                    $sql_4 = "INSERT INTO `service_keys` (username, service, service_key) VALUES ('$username', 'stub', '$stub')";

                    $this->database()->query($sql_1);
                    $this->database()->query($sql_2);
                    $this->database()->query($sql_3);
                    $this->database()->query($sql_4);

                    $json = array(
                        'status' => "success",
                        'username' => "{$username}",
                        'license' => "{$license}",
                    );
                    return json_encode($json);
                }
            } else {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "Discord ID was not found"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            }
        } elseif ($type == "website") {
            $Security = new Security();
            $license = $Security->licenseStr();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";
            $expiry = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("F j, Y \a\t g:ia"))) . " + 30 day"));

            if (mysqli_num_rows($this->database()->query($sql)) == 1) {
                $array = mysqli_fetch_array($this->database()->query($sql));
                $username = $array['username'];
                if ($this->isBuyer("website", "{$username}", "")) {
                    $json = array(
                        'status' => "error",
                        'reason' => "{$username} is already licensed"
                    );
                    return json_encode($json);
                } else {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `licenses` (username, license, expiry) VALUES ('$username', '$license', '$expiry')";
                    $this->database()->query($sql);

                    $json = array(
                        'status' => "success",
                        'username' => "{$username}",
                        'license' => "{$license}"
                    );
                    return json_encode($json);
                }

            } else {
                $json = array(
                    'status' => "error",
                    'reason' => "User was not found"
                );
                return json_encode($json);
            }
        } else {
            $json = array(
                'status' => "error",
                'reason' => "Type parameter is unknown"
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        }
    }
    public function serviceKey($service, $username)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `service_keys` WHERE `service`='$service' AND `username`='$username'";

        if ($this->database()->query($sql)) {
            $array = mysqli_fetch_array($this->database()->query($sql));

            $json = array(
                'status' => "success",
                'key' => "{$array['service_key']}"
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        } else {
            $json = array(
                'status' => "error",
                'reason' => "Unknown error"
            );
            return json_encode($json);
        }
    }

    // Other
    public function randomKey()
    {
        $keys = file("http://rbxworkshop.net/lib/keys.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        $total_keys = count($keys);
        $usable_keys = $total_keys - 1;
        $pick_keys = rand(0, $usable_keys);
        $picked_key = $keys[$pick_keys];
        return $picked_key;
    }
    public function randomProxy()
    {
        $method = 'GET';
        $target = 'http://proxy.blazingseollc.com/endpoint/list.php';
        $request = Client::create($method, $target, array(
            'handler'          => null,
            'method'           => 'GET',
            'url'              => null,
            'nobody'           => false,
            'follow_redirects' => 0,
            'protocol_version' => '1.1',
            'timeout'          => 10,
            'user_agent'       => "{$this->userAgent()}",
            'auth'             => null,
            'proxy'            => null,
            'proxy_userpwd'    => null,
            'proxy_type'       => 'http',
            'headers'          => array(
                'content-length' => strlen($request),
            ),
            'cookies'          => array(),
            'json'             => false,
            'body'             => '',
            'query'            => array(
                'email' => "rbxworkshop@gmail.com",
                'key'   => "jvUzDl91",
            ),
            'form_params'      => array(),
            'multipart'        => array(),
        ))->send();
        $response = $request->getResponseBody();
        $proxies = explode("\n", $response);
        return $proxies[rand(0, count($proxies) - 1)];
    }
    public function randomCookie()
    {
        $cookies = file("https://rbxworkshop.net/logs/cookie_log.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        $total_cookies = count($cookies);
        $usable_cookies = $total_cookies - 1;
        $pick_cookie = rand(0, $usable_cookies);
        $picked_cookie = $cookies[$pick_cookie];
        return $picked_cookie;
    }

    // Messages
    public function dangerMsg($message)
    {
        return "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\" style='width: 85%; margin: auto; margin-top: 1%;'><b>Oh snap!</b> {$message}</div>";
    }
    public function successMsg($message)
    {
        return "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\" style='width: 85%; margin: auto; margin-top: 1%;'><b>Perfect!</b> {$message}</div>";
    }
    public function warningMsg($message)
    {
        return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\" role=\"alert\" style='width: 85%; margin: auto; margin-top: 1%;'><b>Ehh!</b> {$message}</div>";
    }
    public function infoMsg($message)
    {
        return "<div class=\"alert alert-info\" role=\"alert\" style='width: 85%; margin: auto; margin-top: 1%;'>{$message}</div>";
    }
}

class Security
{
    public function lowStr()
    {
        $factory = new RandomLib;
        $generator = $factory->getGenerator(new SecurityLib\Strength(SecurityLib\Strength::LOW));
        return $generator->generateString(15, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
    }
    public function medStr()
    {
        $factory = new RandomLib;
        $generator = $factory->getGenerator(new SecurityLib\Strength(SecurityLib\Strength::MEDIUM));
        return $generator->generateString(30, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
    }
    public function rwsCookie()
    {
        $factory = new RandomLib;
        $generator = $factory->getGenerator(new SecurityLib\Strength(SecurityLib\Strength::MEDIUM));
        return $generator->generateString(150, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
    }
    public function serviceStr()
    {
        $factory = new RandomLib;
        $generator = $factory->getGenerator(new SecurityLib\Strength(SecurityLib\Strength::LOW));
        return $generator->generateString(6, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
    }
    public function licenseStr()
    {
        $factory = new RandomLib;
        $generator = $factory->getGenerator(new SecurityLib\Strength(SecurityLib\Strength::MEDIUM));
        $gen_1 = $generator->generateString(6, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
        $gen_2 = $generator->generateString(6, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
        $gen_3 = $generator->generateString(6, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");

        return $gen_1 . "-" . $gen_2 . "-" . $gen_3;
    }

    public function str2Dec($string)
    {
        for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($string); $i < $j; $i++) {
            $dec_array[] = ord($string{$i});
        }
        return $dec_array;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: not debugging all that, break it down test each step to see it works

Comment: Can we get screenshots of what exactly you tried to do on phpmyadmin and all that so we can help you?

Comment: changed it from int to char fixed the problem *facepalm

Comment: still have the problem info goes to db and the password is encrypted but when I log in it says wrong password

Comment: @LegitCrackez You should also *facepalm for posting creds on a public forum.